# Algolia crawler recordExtractor function doesn't get called at all

Tags: algolia

I'm trying to integrate the Algolia Docsearch in our application, but so far I haven't managed to configure it correctly. I believe that the function assigned to the recordExtractor field in the crawler config doesn't get executed at all.

This is part of my configuration for the actions array

```
actions: [
    {
      indexName: "elumity",
      pathsToMatch: ["https://elumity.com/resources/documentation/**"],
      recordExtractor: ({ helpers }) => {
        console.log("Does not get called at all");
        return helpers.docsearch({
          recordProps: {
            lvl1: ["header h1", "article h1", "main h1", "h1", "head > title"],
            content: ["article p, article li", "main p, main li", "p, li"],
            lvl0: {
              selectors: "",
              defaultValue: "Documentation",
            },
            lvl2: ["article h2", "main h2", "h2"],
            lvl3: ["article h3", "main h3", "h3"],
            lvl4: ["article h4", "main h4", "h4"],
            lvl5: ["article h5", "main h5", "h5"],
            lvl6: ["article h6", "main h6", "h6"],
          },
          aggregateContent: true,
          recordVersion: "v3",
        });
      },
    },
  ],
```

As you can see I have a `console.log()`  in the function, but when I test any valid URL, in the console I get `Nothing was logged from recordExtractor`  which makes me believe that the function doesn't get called at all.

If it is of any help this is the entry to our documentation page, which is the starting point for the crawling process https://elumity.com/resources/documentation/

Please let me know if there is anything else I can provide, that can be of any help.

So far I've tried to edit the crawler configuration object but anything I tried led to the same result. Also I followed the guidelines from Algolia for structuring our pages correctly. I'm not saying that I'm sure that everything is correct, but as it seems the function doesn't get called and also there are no errors or whatsoever reported by the crawler or the URL tester in the admin panel.